# Powerpoint treats text boxes as images?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, posters

I am preparing a poster and I am doing it the first time in my life using Powerpoint. As shown below I have written all my sections around the actual template to format them later on. I saved the file and when I went back I cannot edit or move the text boxes. I can move the pictures with no problem though! There is a solid outline around the text boxes instead of the dotted one in normal case.

[image]

This is what options I have when I select any of the text boxes:

[image]

It's as if Powerpoint treats them as images. Can something be done here? Or do I need to do it all again?

Comment: If you have any choice in the matter dont design in powerpoint. Even if image sizes seem reasonable for you now, they will look like crap when you print them

Comment: I know, I always use latex, but the template I received was given in powerpoint ;/

Comment: Then you suold know that office has a habit of rastrizing vector drawings on innoportune moments.

Comment: Yeah I found out what the issue is. Apparently I saved is as ppt version for office 97-2003, and those don't allow to edit stuff after saving. Nevermind that I am using powerpoint 2019!. I hate office with passion :)